# By clicking on cancel in confirm box close my parent window . I want that on cancel it should be on same page

Tags: javascript

Clicking on cancel in confirm box closes my parent window. I want that on cancel it should stay on same page. I have written the following code for it.

```
function closeEditorWarning(){
    var r=confirm("This will close all the opened windows of application.Do you want to continue.");
    if (r==true)
    {   
         for (var i=0;i<childWindow.length;i++) {
                if (childWindow[i] && !childWindow[i].closed)
                    childWindow[i].close();
              }
         self.close();
         }
   else
      {
      }
}
window.onbeforeunload = closeEditorWarning;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing the `self.close();`?

edit:  try this...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    closeEditorWarning();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: yes I have tried with that and I also put alerts on self.close() but that is not being called on pressing cancel.

Comment: Paul, Pressing on ok or Cancel takes me to another popup of Are you sure you want to leave this page. I dont want this second popup . My code functionality is on Pressing ok all my child windows and parent windows are closing which is OK but on pressing cancel child windows are not closing but parent window is closing and I dont want that